# emitting component declaration files with correct types based on propTypes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollupjs, react-proptypes

I'm building a react/js library with rollup, I am using typescript to emit declaration files for my components, but despite having propTypes for my components, the emitted `.d.ts` files have type of `any` on all the props. Is it possible to let typescript infer types based on my proptypes?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a promising tool: [Ratchet](https://github.com/mskelton/ratchet)